# How to define an embedding from $L$ to $M_{2 \times 2}(L)$?

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $L \supset \mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$-adic field such that $[L: \mathbb{Q}_p]< \infty$. Consider the ring $M_{2}(L)$ of all $2 \times 2$ matrices over $K$ and consider the subring $D_2$ of all diagonal matrices of $M_2(L)$.

How to define an embedding $L \hookrightarrow D_2 \subset M_2(L)$ ?

Here is my try:

Take the Frobenius map $\sigma$ on $L$ and define the map $\iota: L \hookrightarrow D_2 \subset M_2(L)$ by $$\iota(a)=\text{diag}(a, \sigma(a)) \in D_2$$ for any $a \in L$.

This gives us an embedding from $L$ to $M_2(L)$ such that $\iota(a)$ is a diagonal matrix.

Am I right ?

Any comment please

Comment: Yes. You could also just do $a\mapsto aI$. Works for any ring $L$.

Comment: @runway44, thanks. So I think there are countably many way to define an embedding. But in our case there only finitely many ways because we are mapping to diagonal matrices, a restriction. Am I right ?

Comment: BTW there isn't always a 'Frobenius'. Example, $L ={\mathbb Q_3}(t)$, with $t^3 =3$, is not Galois over $\mathbb Q_3$.

Comment: @peterag, If $L$ is an unramified extension  of $K$, then it will be Galois and hence there will be Frobenius. Am i right ?

Comment: If $L/K$ is unramified, yes, it is Galois and there is a Frobenius. But the 'hence' in your phrase "then it well be Galois and hence there will be Frobenius" is wrong. One typically (?) speaks of 'Frobenius' only when the Galois group of the $L/K$ is isomorphic  to that of the residue fields $l/k$, and the (arithmetic) Frobenius is the UNIQUE element of Gal($L/K$) that reduces to $x\mapsto x^q$, with $q$ the cardinality of $k$. For instance, a totally ramified Galois extension has no Frobenius, e.g., $L/K={\mathbb Q}_3(\sqrt -3)/{\mathbb Q}_3$.

Comment: @peterag, thanks for the nice comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the comments, not every finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_p$ has a Frobenius map. An example of such a finite extension of $\Bbb{Q}_3$ is $L=\Bbb{Q}_3[X]/(X^3-3)$.

On the other hand, for every commutative ring $R$ the map
$$R\ \longrightarrow\ D_{2\times2}(R):\ r\ \longmapsto\ \begin{pmatrix}r&0\\0&r\end{pmatrix},$$
is an injective ring homomorphism. Of course so is
$$R\ \longrightarrow\ D_{2\times2}(R):\ r\ \longmapsto\ \begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1(r)&0\\0&\sigma_2(r)\end{pmatrix},$$
for any pair of endomorphism $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\in\operatorname{End}(R)$ with $\ker\sigma_1\cap\ker\sigma_2=0$.

In your particular case $R=L$ is a field, so every endomorphism is either an automorphism or $0$, and we can take any pair of endomorphisms that are not both $0$.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb Q_p$ or any other field of characteristic $0$ perfect, by definition? (And, in your definition of an example of $L$, what is $t$? ...)

Comment: @paulgarrett You are right, though 'by definition' seems like a bit of a stretch. Depends on your definition maybe :) Anyway I corrected; I got my example mixed up and $t=3$. Time for bed here.

Comment: the terminology in your revised example that would be more familiar to me anyway is "(totally) ramified", as a reason that a (characteristic $0$) Galois group has no (non-trivial) Frobenius element (lifted from a residue class field, etc.)

Comment: @Servaes, You defined an embedding  $R \to D_{2 \times 2}(R)$.  Can we consider the same map as an embedding $R \to M_{2 \times 2}(R)$ instead of $R \to D_{2 \times 2}(R)$ ?

Comment: Of course, by embedding $D$ into $M$ in the obvious way.

Comment: @Servaes, Is $r \mapsto rI_{2 \times 2}$ an injective homomorphism when we consider the map from $R \to M_{2 \times 2}(R)$ ? Because every element $r \in R$ is just mapping to the diagonal elements of $M_{2 \times 2}(R)$ only but $M_{2 \times 2}(R)$ has more elements besides diagonals. So how is it injective in order to be anembedding ? It is not clear me